# What is a good algorithm to distribute items with specific requirements?

Tags: algorithms, distribution

I have to programmatically distribute a set of items to some entities, but there are rules both on the items and on the entities like so:

```
Item one: 100 units, only entities from Foo
Item two: 200 units, no restrictions
Item three: 100 units, only entities that have Bar

Entity one: Only items that have Baz
Entity one hundred: No items that have Fubar
```

I only need to be pointed in the right direction, I'll research and learn the suggested methods.

Comment: What's Foo? What "100 units" means? What's Baz?

Comment: Does it really matter? Its just a set of rules to be matched, it could be "contains gluten" or "is red"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is something like this:

```
for item in items
    for entity in entities
        if entity.allows(item) and item.allows(entity)
           entity.associate(item)
           break
```

If you have millions of items and entities, and strict performance requirements, then you'd have to get into creating indices for each of the criteria, like a list of all `Foo` entities, etc.  That's going to add a lot of complexity though, so I wouldn't do it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: The most straightforward way is also usually the most easily maintained.  The next programmer to visit this code will thank you.